# committing "inner" transactions on T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am working on a large SQL Server stored procedure which is called by an integration engine, of which I have no access to the IE code (probably VB6) and I know it initiates a SQL Server transaction from this IE code (it rolls back the changes made by the stored procedure). I know SQL Server ignores the commits of inner transactions (at least that is what I have read on the MSDN site)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336.aspx

But does that count for transactions initiated in calling code that isn't SQL Server / T-SQL code ?

What I am trying to achieve is a database based logging system inside both Oracle and SQL Server stored proc, where the logging wont be rolled back if the update code fails.  I have no control over the outer transaction and I cant partially commit the outer transaction , it has to be all or nothing for the outer transaction.  I have no control of the outer.  For SQL Server , I believe writing an extended stored procedure that simply writes to a table, maybe a solution that isolates itself from the outer transaction

Comment: SQL Server doesn't *ignore* commit or rollback from inner transactions - those are just applied to the entire stack of all transactions. So committing the "inner" transaction really commits **all** transactions that are currently active. SQL Server doesn't really support nested (independent) transactions - it has the syntax, but doesn't really support this

Comment: sql server doesn't have nested transactions; calling code that thinks it does will likely experience unexpected behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the replies, maybe I wasn't clear enough, what I am asking is if calling code transactions from say .net or vb6, are they actually the same as transactions initiated within a SQL server stored proc?

Comment: What are you trying to achive?